Average fetch latency per event in Kafka
I have a consumer group that is consuming and processing events from a kafka topic.
I want to estimate approximately the time to fetch a single record/event. Would that formula approximate such average fetch latency:
 fetch-latency-avg/records-per-request-avg (both values are consumer metrics).

Note that I have already set min.fetch.bytes=1 and fetch.max.wait.ms=0 (in my topic there is always abudant records available anyway)
Any other suggestion on a more reliable metric to compute the avg fetch time per event.
